# antlr4: return values, understanding design

Tags: python, antlr4

I have written my grammar and generated stubs for Visitor. I also subclassed Visitor in order to evaluate my expressions. However, I am facing an understanding problem, since my Evaluator (sublassed from Visitor) is only good for, well, visiting. I dont understand how to make it explicitly return result? It's easy to set something like `self.result` to a final value, and read it later, but it becomes tricky when my expression is recursive.

Also, it seems wierd to me that I need to instanciate Lexer, Stream,Parser, Tree for every expression, as opposite to instanciate only once, and pass multiple expressions to it.

May be Visitor and Evaluator are different things?.. How should I eval my expressions?

Answer (score 0):

One defining characteristics of the Visitor pattern in ANTLR is that the class you create to extend/implement the Visitor can return an object.  When creating a domain specific language, I needed an expression evaluator and found a great project, Bart Kiers' excellent Mu [project located here](https://github.com/bkiers/Mu).  It's not in python, but the idea of the Mu Value object, which can hold representations of different type of expression, is a great starting point for creating your own expression evaluator.

And no, when you're doing it right, you don't need to reinstantiate everything for each expression.  Again, see Bart's excellent implementation for an example of an expression evaluator (with for and while looping thrown in for good measure).

Comment: My mistake, actually I forgot to override the visitProgram (or whatever the name of root element is.) So obviously I was only visiting children. When I overridden  visitProgram, I could return a value from EvalVisitor.